# Python Removing Custom Stop-Words from CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, directory, stop-words

Hi I am new to Python programing and I need help removing custom made stop-words from multiple files in a directory. I have read almost all the relevant posts online!!!!

1. I am using Python 2.7
2. Here are two sample lines of one of my files.I want to keep this format and just remove the stop-words from the rows:
3. "8806";"Demonstrators [in Chad] demand dissolution of Legis Assembly many hurt as police disperse crowd.";"19"
4. "44801";"Role that American oil companies played in Iraq's oil-for-food program is coming under greater scrutiny.";"19"
5. I have a list of stop-words in a dat file called Stopwords.
6. This is my code:

   ```
   import io  
   import os  
   import os.path  
   import csv  

   os.chdir('/home/Documents/filesdirectory')
   stopwords = open('/home/StopWords.dat','r').read().split('\n')

   for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()): 
       name= os.path.splitext(i)[0]    
       with open(i,"r") as fin:
            with open(name,"w") as fout:
                 writer=csv.writer(fout)
                 for w in csv.reader(fin):
                     if w not in stopwords:
                          writer.writerow(w)
   ```

It does not give me any errors but creates empty files. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the output looks like you expected?

Comment: Thanks georgexh. The output should look like: 
"8806";"Demonstrators Chad Legis Assembly police crowd.";"19"
"44801";"Role American oil companies Iraq's oil-for-food scrutiny.";"19"

Comment: and the stopwords list?

Comment: a file with 30000 words in each line. Like:
crosscutting
crossdesignated
crossdressing
crossed
crossfertilized
crossing
crossred

Comment: in your code `w` is a "row", a list of strings, you should filter by each field.

Comment: The main problem is not whether each field (column) is correctly changed. The problem is that the output of the above code is empty files. I thought NLTK might be the solution but that has not worked either.

Comment: because the last expression is always False

Comment: To tell you the truth, I do not know what you mean by "last expression is always False." That is because of my lack of knowledge, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import os
 import os.path
 os.chdir('/home/filesdirectory')
 for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    filein = open(i, 'r').readlines()
    fileout = open(i, 'w')
    stopwords= open('/home/stopwords.dat', 'r').read().split()

    for line in filein:
        linewords= line.split()
        filteredtext1 = []
        filteredtext1 = [t for t in linewords if t not in stopwords]
        filteredtext = str(filteredtext1)
        fileout.write(filteredtext + '\n')
```

Well, I solved the problem. 
This code removes the stopwords(or any list of the words you give it) for each line, writes each line to a file with the same filenmae and at the end replaces the old file with a new file without stopwords. Here are the steps:

1. declare the working directory
2. enter a loop to go over each file
3. open the file to read and read each line using readlines()
4. open a file to write
5. read the stopwords file and split its words
6. enter to a for loop to deal with each line separately
7. split the line to words
8. create a list
9. write the words of the line as items of the list if they are not in the stopwords list
10. change the list to string
11. write the string to a file